# error: invalid operands of types 'int [1]' and 'float' to binary 'operator*'

Tags: c++

I get an error when I run my code:

> error: invalid operands of types 'int [1]' and 'float' to binary 'operator*'

Codeblocks is telling me that the error appears in front of the "ct = ... "?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
float dt = 0.01;
int p = 50;
float ct = 0;
int main()
{
 int state [5][1] = {5,5,0,100,0 };
 // cout << *state[3];

for (float i = 0; i < 10; i+dt){
ct = (state[0]+(2*state[4]/state[5])* sin(state[4]*dt/2)*cos(state[2+state[4])*dt/2);

    }

}
```

Comment: you probably meant `int state[5] = { 5,0,0,100, 0 };`

Comment: Also you're missing a ] in `ct = (state[0]+(2*state[4]/state[5])* sin(state[4]*dt/2)*cos(state[2+state[4])*dt/2);`

Comment: Apart from all that: why did you chose to use a `float` as your loop counter. That's almost never a good idea…

Comment: I wanted to create a matrix that has 5rows and 1 collum isnt int state [5][1] exactly what I need?

I choose float in the loop counter because I increase it with dt and dt is a float number.

Comment: That line is far too long and complex to reasonably be confident that its correct. You should break down the calculation into a few lines, with variable assignments. This will also give you very clear indications of where your errors are.

Comment: The problem with `float` is that it's subject to rounding errors. 0.01 will almost surely not even be represented exactly as a `float`. In your particular case, it'll be fine because the numbers happen to work out in the end if we assume IEEE 754 binary32 format, which is what `float` will typically be. But, just in principle, if you want a loop that does 1000 iterations, then write a loop that does 1000 iterations. Unless you really want a loop that does just approximately 1000 iterations…

Comment: Just as a classic example: Try to figure out how many iterations this loop will do: `for (float i = 0; i < 10; i += 0.00000001f);`

Comment: Also, note that you do not actually increment `i` in your loop…

Answer (score 0):

You declared `state` to be an array of 5 arrays of 1 `int` each. Since `state` is an array of arrays, `state[i]` is itself an array. So when you write something like, e.g., `state[4]*dt` what you're trying to do here is multiply an array (`state[4]` is an array of one `int`) with a `float` (`dt` is a `float)`. While you can multiply an `int` with a `float`, you cannot multiply an `int[1]` with a `float` (that's what the compiler is complaining about). You will either want to make sure to always access the right subelement of the array inside your array, e.g., `state[4][0]`, or not make `state` an array of arrays in the first place…

Apart from that, there's also a typo in that line, check your brackets.

Comment: Oh how can I create a matrix with 5 rows and 1 collum then?

Comment: You can use `int [5][1]`, that's totally fine. However, if you want to operate on the elements of such a matrix, then you have to properly access these elements. `state[4]` is not a single element of your matrix, it's an entire row. `state[4][0]` is the first element of row 4…

Comment: Oh I think I got what you mean. I implemented this earlier in MatLab choosing the element is a bit different there. So when I want to use the element 100 in my array I have to do it like this state[3] [1] * dt and so on

Comment: There is no element `state[3][1]`. Arrays start at 0 in C++. Each row only has a single element. The element with value 100 would be `state[3][0]` in your example above.

Comment: Right thats what I meant. Sometimes its very confusing when you switch between languages. Some are starting the index with 1 and some with 0 well I fixed it now thanks for helping ! :)

Comment: @Jimmy589 indeed. Be aware that C++ arrays are much more basic than matrices in MATLAB. An array in C++ is really just a sequence of elements, nothing else. Also, C++ array declarations do have [weird, unintuitive behavior in certain situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying). If you're not that experienced, I would suggest to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain arrays. `std::array` will still give you nothing but a simple sequence of elements, but at least it will not have any of that weird behavior…